# Proof that an $n-1$-cycle and an element of order $2$ do not commute

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

I tried to prove the following:

Let $n=2k$ be even and let $\sigma \in S_n$ be an $n-1$-cycle and let $\tau \in S_n$ be an element of order $2$. Then $\sigma \tau \neq \tau \sigma$.

> Please could someone check my proof and tell me if it is correct?

Proof:

Write $\tau$ as a product of disjoint transpositions. Since a transposition contains two distinct numbers the product representing $\tau$ contains an even number of numbers.

Case $1$: If the product contains all $n$ numbers then let $i$ be the number not contained in $\sigma$ so that $\sigma (i) = i$ but $\tau (i) = j \neq i$ and $\sigma (j) \neq j$.

Then $\sigma \tau (i) = \sigma (j) \neq j$ but $\tau \sigma (i) = \tau (i) = j$.

Case $2$: If the product representing $\tau$ contains less than or equal to $2k - 2$ numbers then let $i$ be such that $\tau (i) = i$ but $\sigma (i) = j_1$.

Then $\sigma \tau (i) = \sigma (i) = j_1$ and $\tau \sigma (i) = \tau (j_1)$. If $\tau (j_1) \neq j_1$ then we are done.

Otherwise, consider $j_2 = \tau (j_1)$. Let $j_3 = \sigma (j_2)$. Then
$\sigma \tau (j_1) = \sigma (j_2) = j_3$ and $\tau \sigma (j_2) = \tau (j_3)$.

Proceed in this fashion. If $\tau (j_k) = j_k$ for $1\le k \le \text{len} (\tau)$ then $\tau = \text{id}$, a contradiction.

Therefore there must be $k$ such that $\tau (j_k) \neq j_k$ but $\tau (j_{k-1}) = j_{k-1}$.

But then $\sigma \tau(j_{k-1}) = \sigma (j_{k-1})\neq j_{k-1}$ and $\tau \sigma(j_{k-1}) = \tau (j_{k-}) = j_{k-1}$.

> And if it is correct, is there a better (shorter) way to prove this?

Comment: Let $i$ be the unique fixed point of $\sigma$. I think you can get away with two cases: $\tau(i)=i$ (in which case we're really living in $S_{n-1}$) and $\tau(i)\ne i$. The exact number of non-fixed-points of $\tau$ probably doesn't matter. Note also that it suffices to prove that $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1} \ne \sigma$; and the conjugation of one permutation by another is very well understood—see for example http://math.mit.edu/~mckernan/Teaching/12-13/Spring/18.703/l_6.pdf .

Comment: I wonder whether the pigeonhole principle would be of any use here, for there are $n$ elements $S_n$ is acting on but only $n-1$ for the $(n-1)$-cycle. The transposition $\tau$ might have something to do with the the element left over (*i.e.*, the hole with two pigeons in). I'm not sure though.